# TestNg - Exclude a class(testrunner) via mvn command line

Tags: maven, cucumber, testng

**Description :**

As a user, I would like to exclude a class ( Test Runner ) when I am running `mvn clean test`

**Pseudo Code :**

`~ mvn clean verify -Dexclude=SampleTest`

How I run my build :

`~ mvn clean verify`; this triggers a surefire plugin that targets the `testng.xml`

**XML: ( TESTNG )**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Automated UI Tests">
    <test name = "Cucumber Test" verbose="2">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.testrunners.SampleTest"/>
            <class name="com.testrunners.Sample2Test"/>
            <class name="com.testrunners.Sample3Test"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I tried grouping ( `@Test groups=sample` ), but that doesn't seem to work with my case.

Not sure if it matters, but here's a snippet of my test runner.

```
package com.testrunners;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features =  {
                "src/test/java/com/features/",
        },
        glue = {
                "com.stepdefinitions"
        },
        monochrome = true,
        tags =  {
                "@smoke"
        },
        plugin = {"pretty",
                "html:target/cucumber/sample",
                "json:target/cucumber-report/sample/cucumber.json",
                "json:target/sample/cucumber.json",
                "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter: target/sample/report.html"}
)

public class SampleTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using maven failsafe plugin?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems to me you are using maven failsafe plugin for execution.

2 approaches can be used:

**From Maven Failsafe plugin:**

You can can use `excludes` property in POM.xml. Please see the configuration to do it. Reference from Maven failsafe official doc plugin.

```
1   <project>
2     [...]
3     <build>
4       <plugins>
5         <plugin>
6           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
7           <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
8           <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
9           <configuration>
10            <excludes>
11              <exclude>**/CircleIT.java</exclude>
12              <exclude>**/SquareIT.java</exclude>
13            </excludes>
14          </configuration>
15        </plugin>
16      </plugins>
17    </build>
18    [...]
19  </project>
```

You can check this here:

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

This way you can run test cases using

```
mvn clean verify
```

**From TestNG:**

Test `classes` and `class` cannot be directly excluded; however, you can exclude classes through groups:

```
@Test(groups = { "ClassTest1" })
public class Test1 {

  public void testMethod1() {
  }

  public void testMethod2() {
  }
```

}

Then you will define the testng.xml:

```
<suite>
  <test>
    <groups>
      <run>
        <exclude name="ClassTest1"/>
      </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
      <class name="Test1">
    </classes>
  </test>
```